# Congratulations on 100k, HLGEM!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations, @HLGEM !

I've always enjoyed your answers. Always thoughtful.

Well done.

Comment: A gem indeed...

Comment: Well done HLGEM, I enjoy your contributions as well.

Comment: @HLGEM Congrats, I have gained a lot from reading your posts. Thanks.

Comment: @HLGEM Congratulations!  I always enjoy hearing your perspective.

Comment: Whenever I see "answered by HLGEM" on the front page I know I'm in for something good.  Thanks for all your contributions to the site!

Comment: @keshlam funny, I've never read her username like that before, but now it seems obvious. I agree with everyone here that I greatly appreciate her contributions!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you.  If you are wondering about the Username, as it seems from the comments, it is a shortening of the registered name of a horse I used to own, Holly's Little Gem. She really was a gem too.